# Comparing an array to another array in an ArrayList

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to programming in C#. I'm trying to build a lottery program(WinForm) that accepts player's numbers and name & puts them into an ArrayList. What I'm having trouble with is comparing the array ot the lottery numbers to the array of each player in the ArrayList. For example:

```
public class Player
{
    public String name;
    public Int32[] playerNbrs = new Int32[6];
}

public class Data
{
    public static ArrayList arrayPlayers = new ArrayList();

    public static int[] lotteryNbrs = new int[6];
}
```

I know I'm supposed to use `SequenceEqual` but I'm having trouble extracting the array of each player in the ArrayList and comparing it to `int[] lotteryNbrs`!

Any advice is appreciated !

Comment: Why is an `ArrayList` used in the first place? It is nicer to code with generic types (like `List<Players>`), and you avoid casting (and in the case of value types, boxing). Since the generic collections will implement the generic `IEnumerable<out T>`, Linq will be easy to apply.

Comment: A Player wins also if its numbers are not in the same order of the extracted numbers? I mean `Player1=1,2,3,4,5,6 LotteryNumbers=6,5,4,3,2,1` Player1 wins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `OfType` method like this:

```
// if theWinner is null it means there is no winner
var theWinner = arrayPlayers
         .OfType<Player>()
         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.playerNbrs.SequenceEqual(lotteryNbrs));
```

BTW, do not ever use `ArrayList`. Use *strongly-typed* collections like `List<Player>` instead...

**Edit:** In the case where there are more than one winners:

```
var theWinners = arrayPlayers
         .OfType<Player>()
         .Where(x => x.playerNbrs.SequenceEqual(lotteryNbrs));
```

Comment: I am too picky, I know, but the winner could be more than one :-)

Comment: @Steve added that too

Comment: @Selman22 : Thanks man. That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks as well for the advice. I guess my teacher didn't care mentioning the advantages of List over ArrayList. I'll keep that in mind !